# Find a string in the list and change value of another property using linq (complicated)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I have two List with a common property i need to compare both and change the final list accordingly

```
class ClassA
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> LstClassB { get; set; }
}

class ClassB
{
    public string PropertyToCompare { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
class ClassC
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> LstClassB { get; set; }
}
class ClassD : ClassA
{
    public bool PropertyToChange { get; set; }
}


 void fun()
    {
        List<ClassC> LstClassC = new List<ClassC>();
        //populate LstClassC

        List<ClassD> LstClassD = new List<ClassD>();
        //populate LstClassD
        foreach (var objectC in LstClassC)
        {
            foreach (var objectBFromClassC in objectC.LstClassB)
            {
                foreach (var objectD in LstClassD)
                {
                    foreach (var objectBFromD in objectD.LstClassB)
                    {
                        if (objectBFromD.PropertyToCompare == objectBFromClassC.PropertyToCompare)
                            objectD.PropertyToChange = newValue;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

so this is what i want to change in LINQ in a efficient way within the list since the LstD is bound to a DataGrid, so everytime i update the value for PropertyToChange based on the same condition i want it to be reflected in DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten each of the two lists of lists that you have into lists of the child elements, and then you can `Join` those two lists together based on the common property.  Using `Join` will be able to use a hash-based lookup to find the matching items from each collection, which will be a lot faster than looking through every single combination, as you're currently doing iteratively.

```
var query = from d in LstClassD
            from dChild in d.LstClassB
            join cChild in LstClassC.SelectMany(c => c.LstClassB)
            on dChild.PropertyToCompare equals cChild.PropertyToCompare
            into matches
            where matches.Any()
            select d;
foreach (var d in query)
    d.PropertyToChange = newValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on how efficient this is, however I'd use Linq's Intersects function.

If you want the below code in an interactive format go to this link https://dotnetfiddle.net/x1gIXQ

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var x = new List<String>();
        x.Add("Hello");
        x.Add("Hola");
        x.Add("Aloha");

        var y = new List<String>();
        y.Add("Goodbye");
        y.Add("Adios");
        y.Add("Aloha");

        var intersects = x.Intersect(y);
        intersects.ToList().ForEach(zz=> Console.WriteLine(zz));

    }
}
```

If you want more information about the intersects function check it out here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx